# Axiom of Choice with randomized choice function

Tags: set-theory, axiom-of-choice

Does the axiom of choice require the choice function to be deterministic or can it be a random function (i.e., its image under some probability space is the set under considertation?)

Comment: A probabilistic function would be a stronger statement; think about the (axiomatic) definition of a random variable or probability space.

Comment: @DanRobertson is that because it implicitly invokes more machinery? Sorry, I'm not familiar enough to glean the actual insight.

Comment: The existence of a random function would imply the existence of a deterministic one. Random variables are only random in the sense that their values depend on observations, not in the sense that we don't know what they could by (and with what probabilities).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"(Choice) function" in the context of the axiom of choice refers to an ordinary, deterministic function.

Comment: if we allow randomized choice functions, do we need the axiom of choice, or can we appeal to the fact that there exists a randomized choice function? Or...is this just restating AC with under probabilistic terminology?

Comment: Can you be more precise about what you mean by a "randomized choice function"?

Comment: For each set $A$, $f(A)$ returns an element of $B$ with some probability. However, if the set cannot be ordered, then I'm concerned this idea falls apart.

Comment: I don't know what that means.  What kind of object is $f$?  What does "probability" mean?  Are you asserting the existence of some probability space which is somehow involved in defining $f$?  For your question to be meaningful, you need to give a complete, precise definition of the terms you are using, not just state some vague intuitive idea.

Comment: Sorry, this question came up as I read some introduction to set theory. $f(A)$ is a random variable, so,  yes, I am assuming some probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F},P)$ such that $f(A)$ is $P$-measurable.

Comment: What does it mean for $f(A)$ to be measurable?  And what conditions are you imposing on $f(A)$ exactly?  Must it _always_ be an element of $A$, or just almost always be an element of $A$?

Comment: f(A) is just like a normal choice function, except there is not deterministic rule that tells you what element from A it will pick, that it all. I think you're making more out of this than I intended.

Comment: My point is that "what you intended" is not mathematically meaningful unless you fill in all these details.  The axiom of choice is fundamentally a statement about "bare sets", with no additional structure that makes words like "measurable" meaningful.  So if you want to refer to such concepts in this context, you need to completely define what you mean.

Comment: I see...I think I am inadvertently both weakening the generality of AC and making a stronger statement about the remainder. I think this is not a good path for me to continue to think about. Thanks for your help!